# Why do sys.schemas and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA return different results?

Tags: azure-synapse

**Why do sys.schemas INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA return different results and which one I should trust?**

On a default azure data warehouse database,

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.schemas
```

returns 4 rows: dbo, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys and sysdiag.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

returns 17 rows, with additional guest, pdw, QTables and db_*.

I'm working an Azure SQLDW editor.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. The two queries should return the same results. I've filed this internally and it should get fixed quickly. Thanks for reporting it.